# An agenda in Korn Shell: New / Edit / Delete / View appointment

Tags: shell, ksh, cron

As stated in the title, I have to write a simple script which should perform some typical agenda's functions. The script must use crontab.
The functions are:

- Creating a new appointment
- Edit an existent appointment
- Delete an appointment
- List the appointment

I really don't have a clue how to do this, can you help me with some hint? Maybe a bit of sweet code?

Thank you very much,
Abaco

EDIT: To be more specific on my question

Point 1: how can I edit a crontab thorugh ksh? How can I insert a new line? Can you link me some documentation or a bit of code about this?

Comment: You really need to show what you have so far. No one wants to do your homework for you, but lots of people here would be willing to help you with specific issues.

Comment: Oh no! I don't want the whole program write down here. I just don't know how to start. But you're probably right, I should be more specific on my question. So point 1: how can I edit a crontab thorugh ksh? I didn't find a decent explanation on the web about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that adds a script that runs at 7:30 AM to your crontab:

```
typeset CURRENT_CRONTAB=$( crontab -l ) # save the current crontab in a variable

print "${CURRENT_CRONTAB}
30 07 * * * /home/tomd/my_script.ksh" | crontab -
```

Yours,
Tom